# How to optimise multiple query into a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following queries:

```
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXCOCD_201906' as tablename,* from HXCOCD_201906
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXCOCL_201906' as tablename,* from HXCOCL_201906
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXICLD_201906' as tablename,* from HXICLD_201906
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXICLM_201906' as tablename,* from HXICLM_201906
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXICND_201906' as tablename,* from HXICND_201906
select top 10 'CISPRO_THXINXT_201906' as tablename,* from HXINXT_201906
```

The query intent is to provide the sample data from the given table

I have nearly 50 queries like above; is there any way to combine the result into a single resultset?

The problem is each table have different column name and the number of columns also differ.

As far my understanding I want to run each query separately and paste into an Excel sheet.

Is there any easier approach to run the query in bulk rather than running indiviudually?

Comment: You can use `union all` or `join`, depending on what you want the result to be.

Comment: Do all the tables have the same definition? If so, that poses the question; why are they separate tables.

Comment: Since you are dealing with different tables with different column counts, then these will have to be run individually. They are individual queries with individual result sets that have no relation to eachother. That being said you could write some VBA using the `ADODB` library to fetch all 6 result sets at once, then iterate through them pasting them to your workbook (if you wanted to automate this). [This article is as old as the hills, but it describes how to deal with multiple recordsets in VBA ADODB](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/083101-1.shtml).

Comment: @Larnu No they don't have same definition.

Comment: Then sounds like `JOIN` is the right choice here; *assuming* those tables have some kind of relationship.

Comment: Table and column names with dated or numbered-suffixes and similar prefixes are signs of sub-optimal database design. As a result, SQL queries tend to be long and complex when few tables and columns in long format should suffice.

Comment: @Ramji ... please show post a sample of table definitions. I still believe there is simiiarity given their names.

Comment: @GordonLinoff got error when used union all since they don't have an equal number of expression as i said column count differs in each table. With respect to join, there is no similar key to join tables

Comment: @Ramji, If they are different column names, how are you able to copy them to excel ? in Excel, are you copying them to single sheet or multiple sheets ?

Answer (score 2):

You can define an structure for the final result-set and supply default values for the missing columns of each table.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    COL1, COL2, COL3, 0 AS COL4, COL5
FROM
    HXCOCD_201906

UNION

SELECT TOP 10
    COL1, COL2, NULL AS COL3, COL4, 0 AS COL5
FROM
    HXCOCL_201906

UNION

....
```

Comment: if there are no duplicates, UNION ALL is preferred, as it is more performant.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the results to csv, so may not meet your needs.

So steps as follows:

1. You need to create a (temp) table of all the tables you need to select from
2. Create a cursor to iterate through the list of table
3. Build a dynamic query to select from table
4. Configure query results for text output: Query -> Query Options -> Results -> Text (see screen shot)

   No headings,Separate tab for result status,Custom separator of your choice
5. Set results to output to txt
6. Run query
7. Right click results "Save results as" csv

Example:

```
--Temp table to hold list of tables
CREATE TABLE #tbls (tblname varchar(20))    

--Add all tables to table list
INSERT INTO #tbls (tblname)
SELECT '1'
UNION ALL SELECT '2'
UNION ALL SELECT '3'
UNION ALL SELECT '4'
UNION ALL SELECT '5'

--Create cursor
DECLARE tblcur CURSOR
    FOR SELECT tblname FROM #tbls
OPEN tblcur

DECLARE @tblname varchar(20)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

FETCH NEXT FROM tblcur
INTO @tblname

--Output contents of tables
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @SQL + 'SELECT ['+ @tblname + '_ID] AS tablename,* FROM dbo.[' + @tblname +']'
    execute sp_executesql @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM tblcur
    INTO @tblname

END

CLOSE tblcur
DEALLOCATE tblcur
DROP TABLE #tbls
```

[image: Query output]